# eBay Digital Signatures for APIs - Random 403s

Tags: digital-signature, ebay-api

My spring boot app is making calls (among others) to the eBay Finances API and in order to be compliant with the latest requirements we sign all of our requests (for all clients no matter if they are from EU / UK or not).

Unfortunately, I am facing some **non deterministic errors** - where I am getting a **403 exceptions from eBay** with the following details :

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorId": 215120,
      "domain": "ACCESS",
      "category": "REQUEST",
      "message": "Signature validation failed",
      "longMessage": "Signature validation failed to fulfil the request."
    }
  ]
}
```

The weird issue is that the exact same request that is failing (randomly) will be successful after a few seconds (I am using the **@Retryable** spring boot annotation that attempts to execute the service method again after a few seconds).

An example request is the following one (for obvious reasons xx-yyyyy-zzz is a masked orderId) :

```
HTTP GET https://api.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v1/order?orderIds=xx-yyyyy-zzz
```

Has anyone else faced such random issues ?

Finally I would like to note that the exception rate is pretty low (every 100k requests only 60 requests will fail like this).

Thanks in advance !